# An applet failed to load or is unavailable

Tags: firefox, applet, browser, websphere-portal, lotus-wcm

I am getting this error on IE 8 ,9  firefox and chrome. while editing content in WebSphere Portal 7.

IWKAP0010W: An applet failed to load or is unavailable. Certain Web Content Management features will not be available.

Is there any way to solve this.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the Java plugin installed in your web browser.

Comment: Do you know which theme you are using for your Portal 7 admin interface?

Answer (score 0):

You need us to give a bit more information:

- **Q**: Which exact version of ws portal are you using?
  **A**: 7.0.0.2 (your answer)
- **Q**: Which [culmulative fix (CF) level](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24029452) have you installed? (cp. fixes below)
  **A**: ?
- **Q**: What java version have you installed (which is running in the webbrowser)?
  **A**: ?
- **Q**: Did you check the java plugin and the webbrowser security settings?
  **A**: ?

Maybe your issues have been fixed with a CF?

- in [CF027](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24029452#CF027) Issue/[Apar](http://www-947.ibm.com/systems/support/fixes/en/fixcentral/help/faq_sw.html#apar) PI09604 (they fixed compatibility with 7u51)
- in [CF022](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24029452#CF022) Issue/APAR PM88690 (fixed security warning)
- in [CF021](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24029452#CF021) Issue/APAR PM81772 and PM84580 (Renewal of certificate)
- in [CF010](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24029452#CF010) Issue/APAR PM49505 (firefox problems)
- in [CF002](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24029452#CF002) Issue/APAR PM33239 (chrome problems)

So please update your WP7 to the latest CF and try again. Download and installing instructions are on the page [provided above](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24029452) or [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24027857).

Comment: I am using WebSphere Portal 7

Comment: No with exact I mean the full version like 7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This seems like there is no Java plug-in (since you mention IE8 also gives you this error) on the system you are using to access WCM authoring. Newer, auto-updating browsers such as Firefox and Chrome tend to block all but the absolute latest Oracle Java plug-in for security reasons. However, typically there is a prompt to "allow this time." IE8 doesn't do this, but you'll get the same error message from WCM (IWKAP0010W) if you have no Java plug-in installed.

There are a couple of ways you could resolve this:

- Ensure that you have the latest Oracle Java Plug-In installed in on the computer doing the WCM authoring. Since you mention IE8, I suspect perhaps no Java plug-in is installed at all.
- Change your authoring template to not use rich text at all
- Change your content item or authoring template to use a different rich text editor that does not use a Java applet.  There are others out there; IBM even ships WCM7+ a JavaScript-based rich    editor that is better than plain text but has less features than    Ephox EditLive! and requires no Java plug-in for authoring.

Usually the easiest is to just install Java on the authoring computer.  If that's not an option (for example you don't have installation permission), you could change your content system to no longer require Java applets for editing.

Comment: I installed  firefox and IE of latest version. installed the latest oracle java browser plugins for both, reviewed the setting for java applets. But still getting this issue

Comment: Do you see evidence that the Oracle Java plug-in is ever loading on the page? To verify that Java plug-in works at all on the machine, you can visit http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp